# Deep Customization of a Wordpress Theme CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, firebug

I have a test site where i am implementing a wordpress theme named Oxygen.Now after i have changed the background image of the theme every font color and styles like hover etc need to be changed.

The problem is even if i use custom CSS, it does not reflect any change. In some other cases it shows some changes. A example is when i used hover background in the CSS it changed but when i used hover color it did not reflect any change.

My problem is similar to this

[First link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/theme-oxygen-change-left-navbar-background?replies=11)

My sites link is this [LINK](http://savioursblog.cu.cc/)

I know how to use firebug to identify a particular CSS line but i do not seem to find the area at all.
My major problem is Hover Color,Menu Color,Font Color.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please paste some code here so we can see how you are implementing things. Number of things could be wrong... Specificity is one thing, the other is that your rules might be above the theme's rules and are being overwritten. Paste some code here so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It working fine. I tried to change the color of Menu when hover. and its working. Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #menu-primary ul li a:hover, #menu-primary li ul li a:hover {
        color: #FFC0CB !important;
    }
</style>
```

For example paste this code in header.php and see the changes.